# Traveling Salesman with multiple start points and one end point

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, path, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I am trying to make a Google maps application which involves routing of vehicles from different locations. For example lets say there are three vehicles, each at a different location, and they have to cover 10 locations and reach one common destination. I need to find the most optimum way to cover all the 10 points with the 3 vehicles. I know that the Google Directions API provides a "way point" feature to solve the traveling salesman problem but that's only with one vehicle. I looked at the Vehicle Routing Problem but wasn't able to find an algorithm to solve my problem. I will appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: Does each vehicle have to visit all 10 points?  Or do the points have to be covered by at least 1 vehicle?

Comment: A point only needs to be covered once. It can be covered by any vehicle

Comment: And I assume that it's ok for a car to go directly to the destination without visiting any cities?  Also, are we minimizing distance or time?  If there is a weight on each city saying how much time a driver needs to spend there we could get a very different result.

Comment: I am trying to optimize distance for now. It will be OK if a car doesn't visit any of the cities as long as all the cars combined cover the least amount of distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can be framed as a network flow problem and solved with linear programming.  Most books on linear programming address such problems.  For example here's a [chapter](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter10.pdf) from a book on optimization

In your case I would model your starting locations as sources, the cars as the product being shipped, the cities are the nodes, and the single sink is the final destination.  The weights on the routes are distances.

A special case of the network flow problem is the "shortest route tree problem" (page 8 of the paper referenced above), which sounds like your exact problem, only in reverse: you start at a common point and move to the other nodes.  The solution to your problem should be the same.

Comment: 'Solved with linear programming' cannot be correct, because TSP is NP-hard whereas linear programming is polynomial time. Maybe you mean the problem can be framed as INTEGER linear programming, and approximated with a standard linear programming relaxation of the ILP?

Comment: @user2566092 This is not the traveling salesman problem at all, it's closer to a minimum spanning tree.  In fact, I think I can reduce it to a special case of a minimum spanning tree problem, by pre-computing the minimum paths on the map between the nodes.

Comment: @Codie CodeMonkey.Thanks for your help. Are you saying first compute the minimum path between every node in the graph and then use the Minimum Spanning tree algorithm? In my case I will need to use Google Maps to calculate the distance from one selected node to all the other nodes and do this for all the nodes.

Comment: @anishk25 It's a little more than that, I'll have to think about how to  how to construct the graph for minimum cost spanning tree.  I understand reluctance to do linear programming however, so I'll play with it.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey I was also thinking about using K-means clustering to divide locations into specific regions. The number of regions will be determined by number of cars. But I think this way will not offer the most optimum way to solve this problem.

Comment: @anishk25 I gave it some thought and couldn't find a way to reduce the problem to minimum cost spanning tree.  The way I first thought didn't pan out because of extraneous leaf nodes.  The way I lay out in my answer is the only want I know.  Some problems are best solved with linear programming!

Answer (score 0):

You could model this as a Travelling Salesman Problem (one salesman who visits all cities and returns to his starting point). The modifications you have to make to the problem are:

The cost to go from the end point to the start points is zero.
The end point should be duplicated as many times as there are cars.

The solution of the TSP will then give one tour that connects all cities with minimal cost. Each path (part of this tour) from one of the start points to one of the copies of the end point is then the route one of the cars should take.

Since this solution can use state-of-the-art TSP solvers, you might get better results than using an algorithm you construct yourself.